# How can we prove that If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a full rank matrix and $m\ge n$, then $A^\top A$ is a positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, least-squares, positive-definite

I'm given the following problem:
Consider the least mean squares problem: 
$$
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\|Ax - b\|^2_2
$$
Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a full rank matrix and $m\ge n$. Find the closed-form solution of the least mean squares problem.

We are given the following Hint:
If  $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a full rank matrix and $m\ge n$, then $A^\top A$ is a positive definite matrix

We can then derive the following solution:
$$
x = (A^\top A)^{-1}b^\top A
$$

**Here is my question**: how can we prove the Hint? (If  $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a full rank matrix and $m\ge n$, then $A^\top A$ is a positive definite matrix)

Comment: Do you know QR decomposition? It can be proved with the help of QR decom. also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any vector $v$ we have $v^\top (A^\top A) v = (Av)^\top (Av) = \|Av\|^2 \ge 0$.
We then need to show that if $v \ne 0$, then this last inequality is strict, i.e. $\|Av\|^2 > 0$.

Suppose otherwise that $v \ne 0$ and $\|Av\| = 0$. Then $Av=0$, so the nullspace of $A$ contains a nonzero vector. By the rank-nullity theorem, the rank of $A$ is thus strictly less than $n$, so it cannot be full rank.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @angryavian. In the second paragraph, didn't  you mean $v\ne 0$ and $\|Av\| = 0$?

Comment: @ecjb Isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: I wanted to wrote, did you mean $v\ne 0$ and $\|Av\|^2 = 0$ but I guess $\|Av\| = 0$ and $\|Av\|^2 = 0$ mutually implies each other right?

Comment: @ecjb Yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Using [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) we obtain $$A=UDV$$therefore $$A^HA=V^HD^HDV$$which can very easily proved to be positive definite.

Comment: Please provide more details. Link-only answers are frowned upon.